# Expectation Value of Particle Number after Bogoliubov Transformation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, statistical-mechanics, condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, many-body

Suppose I have a Hamiltonian of this form :[How can a Bogoliubov transformation be implemented numerically](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/593447/how-can-a-bogoliubov-transformation-be-implemented-numerically). Here, we suppose they are all bosonic operators.
$$\mathcal{H}=\sum_{\vec{k}}\begin{pmatrix}
a_{k}^{\dagger} && b_{k}^{\dagger} && a_{-k} && b_{-k}
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
c && w^{*} && 0 && x^{*}\\
w && c && x && 0\\
0 && x^{*} && c && w^{*}\\
x && 0 && w && c
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
a_{k}\\
b_{k}\\
a_{-k}^{\dagger}\\
b_{-k}^{\dagger}
\end{pmatrix}$$

I've implemented Bogoliubov Transformation to get this form: $$\mathcal{H}=\sum_{\vec{k}} \epsilon_k(\alpha_k^\dagger\alpha_k+\alpha_{-k}\alpha_{-k}^\dagger)+\eta_k(\beta_k^\dagger\beta_k+\beta_{-k}\beta_{-k}^\dagger)$$

My question is, how to estimate the number of particles, like $\langle a_k^\dagger a_k\rangle$, $\langle a_k^\dagger b_{-k}\rangle$ or something.

What confused me is that at $T=0$, none of particle will be excited. Thus, the operators like $\langle a_k^\dagger a_k\rangle$, $\langle a_k^\dagger b_{-k}\rangle$ or something should all be **zero**. But after Bogoliubov Transformation, $a_k=u_1\alpha_k+u_2\beta_k+u_3\alpha_{-k}^\dagger+u_4\beta_{-k}^\dagger$ and $a_k^\dagger=u_1\alpha_k^\dagger+u_2\beta_k^\dagger+u_3\alpha_{-k}+u_4\beta_{-k}$, then $$\langle a_k^\dagger a_k\rangle=\langle (u_1\alpha_k^\dagger+u_2\beta_k^\dagger+u_3\alpha_{-k}+u_4\beta_{-k})(u_1\alpha_k+u_2\beta_k+u_3\alpha_{-k}^\dagger+u_4\beta_{-k}^\dagger)\rangle$$

After expanding the above expression, we'll get terms like $\langle \alpha_{-k}\alpha_{-k}^\dagger\rangle=\langle \alpha_{k}\alpha_{k}^\dagger\rangle=1+\langle \alpha_{k}^\dagger\alpha_{k}\rangle=1+\dfrac{1}{e^{\beta \epsilon_k}-1}\overset{\beta\rightarrow\infty}=1$, which is **not zero**.

What's wrong with the derivation process? And how to get the right answer at finite temperature?